# CSS Layout Issues - DIVs & Floats

Tags: html, css

I'm having a couple of bugs with my layout and was wondering if anyone could help me out.  I need to have the white space removed above the nav bar and below the footer. Secondly, I'd like to have all of the footer elements on the same line, instead of being slightly staggered.  I've attached a picture of the site, as well as the HTML and CSS that goes with it.  Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>21st Century Dad</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#26ADE4; float:right; font:14px 'Kanit',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 20px; text-align:center; padding:10px; border-radius:20px;}
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
       We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
</head>

<body>
<header>
    <div id="header-content">
        <img src="../website/images/logo-big.png" alt="21st Century Dad" height="110" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;" /> 

<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->

<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//fb.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=48be460d4492dcbdd2828666e&amp;id=f7d2ed069d" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
Sign up for our newsletter!
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk"></span></div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_48be460d4492dcbdd2828666e_f7d2ed069d" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="background-color:#D1E751; font:14px 'Kanit',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; margin-top:4px; border-radius:5px; border-color:#D1E751;"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">DIY Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dad Tech</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kid Stuff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ask a Dad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dad Jokes</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
<main>

<div class = "container">
<div class = "blocks">
<h1>What's New with Dad?</h1>
<img src="../website/images/whatsnew.png" alt="About Me Picture" style="border:1px solid #000;">
</div>
<div class = "blocks">
<h1>DIY Project of the Week</h1>
<img src="../website/images/diyproject.jpg" alt="DIY Project Picture" style="border:1px solid #000;">
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
<h1>Dad Gadget of the Week</h1>
<img src="../website/images/dadgadget.jpg" alt="Dad Gadget of the Week Picture" style="border:1px solid #000;">
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
<h1>Activity / Meal of the Week</h1>
<img src="../website/images/dadactivity.jpg" alt="Kid Activity & Meal of the Week" style="border:1px solid #000;">
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
<h1>Dad Q & A of the Week</h1>
<img src="../website/images/askadad.png" alt="Dad Q & A of the Week" style="border:1px solid #000;">
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
<h1>Dad Joke of the Week</h1>
<img src="../website/images/dadjokes.jpg" alt="Dad Joke of the Week" style="border:1px solid #000;">
</div>
</div><!-- end container -->


</main>
<footer>  
<div id="footer">
         <p class="left">
        21stcenturydad@gmail.com

        <p class="right">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"> 
        <img src="../website/images/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook Logo"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/"> 
        <img src="../website/images/Snapchat.png" alt="Snapchat Logo"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"> 
        <img src="../website/images/Instagram.png" alt="Instagram Logo"/></a>

         <p class="centered">
        &copy; Copyright 2017 21st Century Dad

</div>
</footer>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:200,300,500');

body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image:url(../website/images/background.png);
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #363636;
}

p {
    line-height: 140%;
}

header {
    background-color: #D1E751;
    width: 960px;
    z-index:1000;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;

}

#header-content {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 130px;
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #26ADE4;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

nav ul {
    display: block;
    padding:14px 0 14px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    padding: 5px 30px 5px;
}

nav a:link {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #D1E751;
    color: #FFF;
}

nav a:visited{color:#FFF;}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top:60px;
}

.container{width:960px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center;}

.blocks{display:inline-block;
        width:300px;
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-right:5px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #26ADE4;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

h2 {
    font-weight:500;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:-2px;
    bottom:-9px;
}

footer {
    background-color: #D1E751;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    clear: both;
}

.left{text-align:left;
font-size:14px;
        float:left;
        padding-top:8px;
        padding-bottom:8px;
}

.right{float:right;
text-align:right;
}

.centered{text-align:center;
font-size:14px;
padding-top:8px;
        padding-bottom:8px;
        max-width:300px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlB0r.jpg)

Comment: The problem with your header is due to that it has an incorrect `height` on `#header-content`. Altering this shifts **everything** around, so you'll need to adjust for that. As for your footer, you should use `display: inline-block` elements rather than padding-offset and floated `<p>` tags.

Comment: Appreciate the help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take out margin:auto to the body to get rid of surrounding whitespace

For a simple footer, you can position the element `fixed` to the screen

For elements in the footer, You can use a display flex property on the div with id footer

CSS rules below and pen is [here](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/MpdLmZ?editors=1100)

```
body {
  margin: auto;
}

.left,
right,
.centered {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```